# WKWebView is not reclaiming after closing the NSWindow

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I have called `window.close()` on an `NSWindowController`. I am getting the window controller `deinit` call. But the NSViewController associated with the window is not reclaiming. The `deinit` of the view controller is not getting called.

The window controller loads a `WKWebView`. I then set the html content to empty before invoking close. I have set nil for all delegate in `deinit` and delegate are all weak.

The activity monitor shows the `Web Content` process.

[image: Web Content Process]

I have code like:

```
class WebKitViewController: NSViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView?
    private lazy var msgService: WebViewMessageService? = {
        let s = WebViewMessageService()
        s.delegate = self
        return s
    }()
    weak var delegate: WebKitDelegate?
    // ...

    func initWebView() {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: self.initWebKitConfig())
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        // ...
    }
}
```

How to reclaim the memory and fully exit the `WindowController` with a `WKWebView` based `NSWindowController`?

---

The close function in the `WebKitViewController` is as below.

```
func closeWindow() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.webView?.uiDelegate = nil
        self.webView?.navigationDelegate = nil
        self.msgService?.delegate = nil
        self.webView?.removeFromSuperview()
        if let window = self.view.window, let wc = window.windowController as? WebKitWindowController {
            Log.debug("Closing window \(wc.windowId)")
            self.webView?.loadHTMLString("", baseURL: nil)
            self.delegate?.closeWindow(windowId: wc.windowId)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `s.delegate = self` delegate weak?

Comment: Do you adding some observers or handlers to WebView?

Comment: @Asperi: Yes, it's a weak var (`weak var delegate: WebViewMessageServiceDelegate?`).

Comment: @AndrewVergunov: Yes, I am adding `uiDelegate`, `navigatorDelegate` and `WKScriptMessageHandler`. I am removing the first two and setting the last as nil in `deinit`, but `deinit` does not get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a well-known bug of WKScriptMessageHandler. Here is similar question by this link: [Memory leak when using WKScriptMessageHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094110/memory-leak-when-using-wkscriptmessagehandler)

What can you do to avoid leaks:

Call `removeScriptMessageHandlerForName()` when you're closing your window.